# How to know how much Voltage/Watts a device uses

Tags: 11.10

I wanted to know if there is a terminal command or GUI app that can show me for example how much electricity (Watts, Voltage, etc..) a device is using. For example, if I have 3 hard drives, how much they are using. How much is the motherboard using and any other device.

Is it possible to check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to get estimates of the wattage a specific device/process is using with PowerTOP. In order to get estimates of the amount of power that is being used, rather than just the % of wakeups from specific processes, it is important to first calibrate powertop.

```
sudo powertop --calibrate
```

This takes time as it performs various tests whiles switching different devices on and off. You **must not** touch the machine during calibration. When calibration is done it will start PowerTOP as normal. Now you must leave PowerTOP running to allow it to gather data. After approximately an hour, power estimations will begin appearing in the first column.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this from within a shell - the software doesn't have any way of knowing how much power is consumed as you need to measure the current drawn by the PSU to get a good reading of power consumption.

I did this for my computers (in a reasonably accurate way) with one of the devices power companies give out for free to measure power consumption for your house. I had the remote display sitting in my office and noted what it went to when I turned devices on or off, ran highly CPU intensive apps etc.